# What's the best approach to adding an automated process on deleting records from mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I currently have a chat bot setup to store records onto MongoDB. The object that's stored in Mongo looks like...

```
{ ..., expiration_time: 12451525, ... }
```

Where `expiration_time` is a number represented in minutes.

My initial approach was use `setInterval` on the web application to query the database to delete all records that matched the criteria of current time being greater or equal to expiration time. However, I feel like there would be a lot of additional queries to the database from the web application, when there are already other operations such as reading and writing data.

I read about storing functions onto Mongo, but I'm sure how to automate the process of invoking the function to self delete the records.

I would definitely love any feedback, approach, or guidelines for best practices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a built-in mechanism for this purpose in MongoDB called [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/):

```
db.messages.createIndex( { "expiration_time": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

The only requirement is that `expirtion_time` has to be a date instead of an integer.

> To expire documents at a specific clock time, begin by creating a TTL index on a field that holds values of BSON date type

Comment: Had a question, it seems that this only works if I add new records in. It does not seem to self-expire on it's own.

Comment: @user3593810 Have you converted the `expiration_time` to date for the old documents? Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727743/mongodb-ttl-not-removing-documents

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there are 2 options:

1. One can use a cronjob to remove the out-of-date entries
2. One can use the [Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/). It's like a ring buffer, so that the oldest entry will be overwritten. Here one must choose the right fix-size of the capped Collections. I.e, size = 24 * 60 = 1440 if the chat bot writes every minute to the collection.